# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DetectIntentRequest'

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey i got a flutter error...

---

E/flutter ( 9519): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DetectIntentRequest'

---

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: you need Post your code.

Comment: we need the code to understand the problem properly, please provide the code which is causing the problem + any related classes , function ...etc to it

Comment: From the above mentioned description I think it requires the DetectIntentRequest type and you are passing the String to it so just check if you are passing correct things.